# Tronix cryptocurrency

Tags: wallet, altcoin

How can I create a tronix (trx) cold wallet? I see no info on the Internet. Both a link to a key generator script and website with wallet creation would be ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRX is an ERC20 token so you can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ offline to create a cold wallet. As of now TRX don't have any official wallet.

Here is a how-to [Using MyEtherWallet For Cold Storage](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/offline/ethereum-cold-storage-with-myetherwallet.html)